# Focus first invalid field in form using Rails 5 and simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I use Rails 5 and simple_form gem with Bootstrap preconfigured on installation (if its matter).

The problem is: on form render first field that has error should be focused. In case if there's no errors let's focus the first row.

This gem has ability to use `autofocus: true` on fields, but putting this attribute at every field in form view destroys simplicity of 'simple_form'. The only solution I found is to override check for autofocus field attribute and force to set it when the field has an error and autofocus attribute is not set:

```
module SimpleForm
  module Helpers
    module Autofocus
      private

      def has_autofocus?
        options[:autofocus] == true || has_errors?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For the case when form has no errors I use explicitly set autofocus on first field:

```
= simple_form_for object do |f|
  = f.input :to, autofocus: true
  = f.input :cc
  = f.input :subject
  = f.input :body, input_html: {rows: 10}
```

So, the question is: is there a better way to set autofocus attribute dynamically, without overriding this getter? (No JS please, let's play with plain HTML attributes) I couldn't find a way to implement this scenario using form builders (like builders that simple_form generates at `config/initializers`), but maybe there's a solution with tricky composition of builders? Or maybe there can be a simpler and less dangerous override?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no suitable solution to this issue I came up with a small but hacky solution.

At first you need to enable the inclusion of custom components in your simple_form initializer `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` :

```rb
# Uncomment this and change the path if necessary to include your own
# components.
# See https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#custom-components to know
# more about custom components.
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/components/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Still in the initializer add the `autofocus_on_error` component:

```rb
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
    ...
    # If a form has invalid fields, automatically set the focus on the first
    # field with an error
    b.use :autofocus_on_error
  end
end
```

Now create the actual component in `lib/components/autofocus_on_error_component.rb`:

```rb
module AutofocusOnErrorComponent
  def autofocus_on_error(wrapper_options = nil)
    if has_errors? && !inputs_with_autofocus_present?
      input_html_options[:autofocus] = true
    end

    nil
  end

  private

  def inputs_with_autofocus_present?
    @builder.template.output_buffer.include?('autofocus="autofocus"')
  end
end

SimpleForm.include_component(AutofocusOnErrorComponent)
```

Finally restart your webserver to reflect the changes.